# SwiftUI view as a UITextView inputAccessoryView has incorrect frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swiftui, inputaccessoryview

I am trying to add a SwiftUI view as an accessory view to a `UITextView` through a `UIHostingController`. Following is my `UIInputView` configuration

```
struct AccessoryView: View { /* SwiftUI View */ } 

class AccessoryInputView: UIInputView {

    private let controller: UIHostingController<AccessoryView>

    init(_ attachmentItem: Binding<AttachmentItemType>) {
        let parentView = AccessoryView(selectedAttachmentItem: attachmentItem)
        self.controller = UIHostingController<AccessoryView>(rootView: parentView)
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 44), inputViewStyle: .default)

        self.controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.addSubview(self.controller.view)

        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.widthAnchor),
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.heightAnchor),
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.centerXAnchor),
            self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

I have drawn the border of the `UIInputView` in blue and the have set a border around the `AccessoryView` in red. As you can see in the screenshot the SwiftUI view is offset by couple points. `UITextView` has the borders in green.

Any reason why this happens?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by overriding `AccessoryInputView`'s `safeAreaInsets` like this:

```
struct AccessoryView: View { /* SwiftUI View */ } 

class AccessoryInputView: UIInputView {

    private let controller: UIHostingController<AccessoryView>

    init(_ attachmentItem: Binding<AttachmentItemType>) {
        let parentView = AccessoryView(selectedAttachmentItem: attachmentItem)
        self.controller = UIHostingController<AccessoryView>(rootView: parentView)
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 44), inputViewStyle: .default)

        self.controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.addSubview(self.controller.view)

        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // HERE
    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        .zero
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.widthAnchor),
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.heightAnchor),
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.centerXAnchor),
            self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.controller.view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took @wes's answer and used generics and a builder to make it more reusable:

In essence, I replaced the `AccessoryView` struct with an `AccessoryContent` generic constrained to be a SwiftUI View and then aded a builder method to the `init` method.

To use, all you need is:

```
uiView.inputAccessoryView = AccessoryInputView {
  Text("Hello!")
}
```

`AccessoryInputView.swift`:

```
class AccessoryInputView<AccessoryContent: View>: UIInputView {
    private let controller: UIHostingController<AccessoryContent>

    init(_ accessoryViewBuilder: () -> AccessoryContent ) {
        controller = UIHostingController<AccessoryContent>(rootView: accessoryViewBuilder())
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 44), inputViewStyle: .default)

        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        addSubview(controller.view)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        .zero
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.widthAnchor),
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.heightAnchor),
            centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.centerXAnchor),
            centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been working on something similar. I am building an RTF document editor completely in SwiftUI and my input accessory view is done this way.  I just call this function wherever I define or want to display the inputAccessoryView, like in makeUIView I have this line "textView.setInputAccessory()".  The selectors below are all defined within my extension.

```
extension UITextView {
internal func setInputAccessory()
{
    let activeLinkState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "activeLink")
    let bar = UIToolbar()
    let textformat = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "textformat"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.editView(sender:)))
    let linkformat = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "link"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.linkView(sender:)))
    let bold = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "bold"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.onBold(sender:)))
    let italic = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "italic"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.onItalic(sender:)))
    let underline = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "underline"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.onUnderline(sender:)))
    let activeLink = activeLinkState ? UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "link.circle.fill"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.toggleActiveLink(sender:))) : UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "link.circle"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(self.toggleActiveLink(sender:)))
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))
    let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    bar.items = [textformat, linkformat, spacer, bold, italic, underline, spacer, activeLink, done]
    bar.sizeToFit()
    self.inputAccessoryView = bar
}
}
```